# imported .stl model is tiny. How can I set the scale correctly?

Tags: modeling

I am importing .stl to blender. Once it was imported, the object appeared in blender as a tiny dot at the center of the grid(0,0,0) 
For example, when I created an object with the dimension of 1.18cm X 2.99cm X 3.19cm, then export it to .stl. Later on, I import it to blender, the dimension became 
1.18m X 2.99m X 3.19m. Why does blender change cm to m? is there something I am not setting correctly in Blender?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this would be in the export settings.

Comment: What software package did you used to export the model into .stl from , was it blender you used?

Comment: Thank you all for the Replies. Basically, it happens to any .stls, those I downloaded (created with Maya, SolidWorks...) and the ones I created on Blender. Oh I forgot to mention, I use Blender 2.7.6 for OS X

Answer (score 1):

STL file does not have information about units and their scale, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

So you need to set the units and scale in Blender before importing your stl. This is done on "Scene" tab under "Units" group.

Comment: Ah, I see. that explains why I need to set the unit in Blender. Now how do I know in advance whether the unit is in mm, cm or perhaps in inches if I just downloaded it? I guess by trial and error then? ( I have looked at serval .stls in Hex Fiend, some of them does say what unit in the header bytes, but not all of them, I suppose it depends on what software was used to create the .stl.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and you will have to guess the units. I assume you are working with 3d printers. By convention, 3d printing software expects 1 unit = 1 millimeter. "Cura" will do the guessing for you, it will accept any units and adjust them to millimeters automatically.